# content_for with <% or <%=?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Simple question here. Should content for be:

```
<%= content_for :xyz do %>
or
<% content_for :xyz do %>
```

The Rails docs are ambiguous on this!

Answer (score 2):

According to documentation example(http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper.html) `<%= content_for :xyz%>` is used to emit  stored block of markup, while `<% content_for :xyz%>` is used to declare stored block of markup.

So it should look like this(e.g. app/views/home/index.html.erb fragment):

```
<% content_for :my_block do %>
    <h1>I'm header</h1>
<% end %>
```

And somewhere in another template(e.g. app/views/layouts/application.html.erb fragment):

```
<%= content_for :my_block %>
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be `<%= content_for :xyz do %>`.

Answer (score 1):

You can think of `<%= %>` as an insert and `<% %>` as computation

So in an erb file, you might do something like :

```
<% follower_count = current_user.followers.count %>
<%= follower_count %>
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all.